# Is it correct to use two consecutive dots indicating an abbreviation and a full stop?

Tags: punctuation, abbreviations, writing-style, periods

A quote from ["Bad tendency" (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bad_tendency):

> The principle, formulated in *Patterson v. Colorado*, (1907) was seemingly overturned with the "clear and present danger" principle used in the landmark case *Schenck v. United States* (1919), as stated by Justice Oliver Wendell Holmes, Jr..

Is the usage of two consecutive dots at the end of the sentence correct?

Comment: It depends whether you're writing British English or American English or some other variation.

Comment: @TrevorD Nonsense! There’s never a double dot at the end.

Comment: @tchrist My comment was based on a recent answer/comment. But I can't recall where, nor be bothered to look.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This question actually has two parts: (1) Should an abbreviation such as *Jr* for *Junior* include a period at all? (2) If the abbreviation does take a period and if it appears at the end of a sentence, should the sentence be punctuated to include both the *Jr* period and the end-of-sentence period? The answers to both questions are matters of house style, and consequently may vary from publisher to publisher and from style manual to style manual.

Having said that, I don't think that I've ever seen a house style guide in the United States that endorsed the use of consecutive periods in this situation. Most U.S. publishers intentionally or coincidentally follow the *Chicago Manual of Style*, Fifteenth Edition (2003) on this point:

> **6.122** *No double period.* When an expression that takes a period ends a sentence, no additional period follows [cross reference omitted]. ... [Example:] The study was funded by Mulvehill & Co.

As for Wikipedia's house rule, you can find a relevant discussion (dated 26 April 2009) in Wikipedia's Help Desk Archives, under the heading [Jr. at end of sentence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aHelp_desk/Archives/2009_April_26). The upshot of the discussion appears to be that ending a sentence with "Jr.." is not consistent with Wikipedia style.